# Build error while copying kernel config to the source tree

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, raspberry-pi4

i am trying to compile the defconfig file bcm2711_defconfig, so i am trying to copy the bcm2711_defconfig file to the kernel source path, **kernel-source/arch/arm/configs/**
Please let me know how to overcome from the error. below is the recipe file content.

file name: **linux-raspberrypi_4.14.bbappend**

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://bcm2711_defconfig"

do_preconfigure_prepend(){
    cp ${WORKDIR}/bcm2711_defconfig ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/
}

KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_raspberrypi4 ?= "bcm2711_defconfig""
```

build error:
`ERROR: linux-raspberrypi-1_4.14.68+gitAUTOINC+8c8666ff6c-r0 do_kernel_metadata: A KBUILD_DECONFIG  '/bcm2711_defconfig'  was specified, but not present in the source tree`

Comment: have you tried below solution? give more details if your issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

`do_kernel_metadata` task is executed after `do_unpack` & before `do_patch`, so try to copy your defconfig at the end of `do_unpack` task as below,

```
do_unpack_append(){
    cp ${WORKDIR}/bcm2711_defconfig ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/
}
```